# Change decimal separator in Excel in an old spreadsheet

Tags: ms-office

I created an Excel spreadsheet with Microsoft Excel Version 15.23.2 while the option for the decimal separator was set to `,` (comma). This setting had been made in the Language & Region settings of Mac OS X El Capitan. However, I then copied data into it from a csv file that was using `.` (dot) as the decimal separator. Now, these cells with the dots are not read as numerical, i.e. I cannot sum them up, etc.

I already switched the Language & Region setting under System Preferences to using `.` (dot) as a decimal separator. (System Preferences -> Language & Region -> Advanced -> Number separators: Grouping: `,`, Decimal: `.`)

Then I restarted the computer, opened my file again, and still the floating point numbers in the same spreadsheet are not recognized as numbers by Excel.
When I open a **new** Excel spreadsheet, and enter some floating point numbers using the dot separator, these are recognized as floating point numbers.

Did I miss something? Or could I somehow convert my file into a version using the `.` decimal separator?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Edit: When I copy an entire column with (non-recognized) floating point numbers and paste it into the same place, these cells are then recognized as being numerical. However, when I do this with the entire spreadsheet, it does not work.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an OS X-specific problem to me. Try asking on SuperUser, another SE site: http://superuser.com

Comment: Sorry, but I have to disagree that it is not OS X, or at least in general OS-specific. If you google, you will find that in Windows, the decimal-separator-option is set within the Excel Software, whereas on OS X, it is set in the system-wide options. Hence, I assume this is OS X-specific.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.